# How to implement a C# Winforms database application with synchronisation?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, entity-framework, data-synchronization

**Background**

I am developing a C# winforms application - currently up to about 11000 LOC and the UI and logic is about 75% done but there is no persistence yet.  There are hundreds of attributes on the forms.  There are 23 entities/data classes.

**Requirement**

The data needs to be kept in an SQL database.  Most of the users operate remotely and we cannot rely on them having a connection so we need a solution that maintains a database locally and keeps it in synch with the central database.

Edit: Most of the remote users will only require a subset of the database in their local copy.  This is because if they don't have access permissions (as defined and stored in my application) to view other user's records, they will not receive copies of them during synchronisation.

*How can I implement this?*

**Suggested Solution**

I could use the Microsoft Entity Framework to create a database and the link between database and code.  This would save a lot of manual work as there are hundreds of attributes.  I am new to this technology but have done a "hello world" project in it.

For data synch, each entity would have an integer primary key ID.  Additionally it would have a secondary ID column which relates to the central database.  This secondary column would contain nulls in the central database but would be populated in the local databases.

For synchronisation, I would write code which copies the records and assigns the IDs accordingly.  I would need to handle conflicts.

*Can anyone foresee any stumbling blocks to doing this?  Would I be better off using one of the recommended solutions for data sychronisation, and if so would these work with the entity framework?*

Comment: Why don't you use a GUID for the primary keys? AFAIK the Microsoft Sync Framework relies on this. Also utilizing a timestamp may also prove to be useful long term.

Comment: @Simon, I don't see Microsoft Sync Framework mentioned in the question, although it might be worth investigating.  I'm not aware that Entity Framework supports a distributed disconnected environment in any special way. As the question stands I think it can only be answered subjectively.

Comment: @Jodrell Yes I think it can only be answered subjectively. I was assuming (as he is using SQL Server/Entity Framework) that the OP had looked into Sync Framework - but irrespective of that a GUID will make it easier  to "sync" his data with multiple databases.

Comment: @Aron I am not asking for someone to design the system for me.  I am an experienced programmer but I've not worked much with Winforms/SQL before and never done data sync.  All I am requesting is a few pointers from people, which will tell me what I need to research before making my decision.  There are no other developers in my workplace to discuss this with.

Comment: @Simon I've only looked at the sync frameworks superficially, i.e. read this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sync/cc470041.aspx.  I agree that its subjective, but most things in life are :).

Comment: The question you need to answer is, can I get conflicts when data is INSERTED, UPDATED, DELETED. Then, when this occurs, what is the right resolution i.e. first wins, last wins, some sort of merge? Does it depend on the entity in question, on the type of change, etc. etc? You need to be very clear about this, as it will get confusing fast but, I suspect before you even worry about that you want to model your database correctly. It sounds like you have some sort of logical model envisioned.

Comment: @Jodrell the probability of conflicts is low.  The norm is for users to only edit records that they "own", and other users are likely to just view those records.  The data is important to our business but its not safety critical; so it would be acceptable to give the user the choice of how to deal with conflicts (i.e. overwrite or abandon changes).

Comment: Consider using NoSQL, depending on the complexity of your model. You could try RavenDB, which would handle all your concurrency/sync issues for you at the expense of a more complex DAO.

Comment: Also if the data is hierarchial, don't discount serialize to flat file and use git to sync.

Comment: I will briefly look into NoSQL, RavenDB and git.  However, I suspect these would not be favoured solutions in my organisation - they would prefer technologies they understand.

Comment: @PaulRichards if your organization does not understand SCM, it can't score highly on the Joel test, it should be time to leave. :P

Comment: @Aron I use Subversion.  Its a fairly small company with one software developer - me!  And its a bit early to leave, I've only been there 2 months :)

Answer (score 1):

Synching data between relational databases is a pain. Your best course of action is probably dependent on: how many users will there be? How probably are conflicts (i.e. that the users will work offline on the same data). Also possibly what kind of manpower do you have (do you have proper DBAs/Sql Server devs standing by to assist with the SQL part, or are you just .NET devs).

I don't envy you this task, it smells of trouble. I'd especially be worried about data corruption and spreading that corruption to all clients rapidly. I'd put extreme countermeasures in place before any data in the remote DB gets updated.

If you predict a lot of conflicts - the same chunk of data gets modified many times by multiple users - I'd probably at least consider creating an additional 'merge' layer to figure out, what is the correct order of operations to perform on the remote db.

One thought - it might be very wrong and crazy, but just the thing that popped in my mind - would be to use JSON Patch on the entities, be it actual domain objects or some configuration containers. All the changes the user makes are recorded as JSON Patch statements, then applied to the local db, and when the user is online - submitted - with timestamps! - to merge provider. The JSON Patch statements from different clients could be grouped by the entity id and sorted by timestamp, and user could get feedback on what other operations from different users are queued - and manually make amends to it. Those grouped statments could be even stored in a files in a git repo. Then at some pre-defined intervals, or triggered manually, the update would be performed on a server-side app and saved to the remote db. After this the users local copies would be refreshed from server.

It's just a rough idea, but I think that you need something with similar capability - it doesn't have to be JSON Patch + Git, you can do it in probably hundreds of ways. I don't thing though, that you will get away with just going through the local/remote db and making updates/merges. Imagine the scenario, where user updates some data (let's say, 20 fields) offline, another makes completely different updates to 20 fields, and 10 of those are common between the users. Now, what should the synch process do? Apply earlier and then latter changes? I'm fairly certain that both users would be furious, because their input was 'atomic' - either everything is changed, or nothing is. The latter 'commit' must be either rejected, or users should have an option to amend it in respect of the new data. That highly depends what your data is, and as I said - what will be number/behaviour of users. Duh, even time-zones become important here - if you have users all in one time-zone you might get away with having predefined times of day when system synchs - but no way you'll convince people with many different business hours that the 'synch session' will happen at e.g. 11 AM, when they are usually giving presentation to management or sth ;)

Comment: There will only be about 10-20 users: about 7 of these will work remotely. There is a low probability of conflicts. No record merging is required - it would be acceptable just to give the user a warning if they are overwriting someone else's changes. I can implement this by timestamping the records. However I think I will keep a simple audit trail, along the lines of who has created/edited a record and when (but not what the changes are) - this could also help. There is no manpower other than me - I am the designer/coder/tester/DBA! The application will only be used in the UK (one time zone).